# Bullet: Piercing vs. Deflection

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, simulations, collision

I am trying to create a simulation where a projectile (imagine a bullet) is fired at a surface of some kind. When it collides with the surface, I need to figure out what happens between the bullet and surface.

> Example:
>
> Bullet fired at extremely sturdy object, bounces off the object.
>
> Bullet fired at very soft object, pierces into object.
>
> Bullet fired at thin sturdy object, dents the object but does not pierce it.

1) Does what I'm looking for have a name? I am having problems finding any type of equations that may relate to my examples.

2) Can somebody please explain to me what the forces are in this example and how they interact?

2b) What are the variables that I need to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I think soft-body dynamics is what you're looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_body_dynamics